# Using for loop to get sum of digits

Tags: python-3.x

How can you write the output as of a sum formula as 1+2+3=6 as opposed to just getting the sum i.e 6. I have using the sum(str(num)) to get sum_of_digits.But the output is just 6 not 1+2+3=6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things with the inputs - represent them with a `+` sign in between and also compute the `sum` -

```
def mysum(*args):
    return f'{"+".join(str(_) for _ in args)} = {sum(args)}'
mysum(1, 2, 3)
# '1+2+3 = 6'
```